# Spring Security + PostgreSql - How to debug whats going wrong with authentication since there are no error messages?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-security

I am following Spring in action book and creating a small demo application to enhance my spring knowledge.

When i tried to setup spring security with PostgreSQL and tried to test authenticated requests, I am always getting 403 forbidden error with no error messages in console log.
I would like to understand whats wrong with the code.

I tried to add debug level for security, introduced AuthenticationEventListener to monitor the events etc. But none of them tell me why authentication fails.

Register controller working fine and its saving user details to DB with encoded password.

For complete code please look into https://github.com/vin0010/Spring-Recipe

> SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    //TODO check why it didn't work
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("name")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;

    @Autowired
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/test").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/**").permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .and()
                .jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
}
```

> TestController for authentication check

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping
    public String getDocument(){
        return "success";
    }
}
```

> Registration controller

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void send(@RequestBody RegistrationForm registrationForm) {
        userRepository.save(registrationForm.toUser(passwordEncoder));
    }
}
```

> UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {
    Users findByUsername(String username);
}
```

> UserRepositoryUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service("name")
public class UserRepositoryUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users users= userRepository.findByUsername(userName);
        if (users == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User '" + userName + "' not found");
        return users;
    }
}
```

> Users.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Users implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final boolean enabled;
    private final String role;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(this.role));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return this.enabled;
    }
}
```

> queries for user authentication and authorities check

```
spring.queries.users-query=select username, password, enabled from users where username=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select username, role from users where username=?
```

Since I created my own User table, I need to get the authentication done via this en entity setup.